# Javascript using callback to draw an image to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, callback

I think I'm having a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546035/canvas-drawimage-not-drawing-image-to-canvas), but I would like a little help understanding how to use a callback function and how to implement it for my particular situation. I'm trying to have an image get drawn to a canvas "on demand", i.e. any time a certain function is called. The image is associated with an object I call a Block. A Block has dimensions, coordinates, and a url.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function Block(x, y, width, height, url) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.url = url;
        this.drawBlock = drawBlock;
        function drawBlock() {
              var blockSprite = new Image();
              blockSprite.src = url;
              blockSprite.onload = context.drawImage(blockSprite,x,y,width,height);
        }
  }
```

You can see a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h7pbx/1/). Oddly enough, it works if I link to an image on the web, but fails if I link to an image on my disk. I believe that this is because the onload event occurs before drawBlock is called, and that I need to use callbacks or promises to fix this, but I'm very new to Javascript so I'd like a little guidance here. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try surrounding your code with `window.onload=function(){};`

Comment: @JamesBrown Actually, I already have that surrounding all my code. I have a couple things drawn to the canvas as soon as they are ready, and that part of it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function Block(x, y, width, height, url) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.url = url;
        this.drawBlock=function drawBlock(){
              var blockSprite = new Image();
              blockSprite.src = url;
              blockSprite.onload = function(){
                  context.drawImage(blockSprite,x,y,width,height);
              }
        }
  }

var block=new Block(0,0,32,32,"house32x32.png");
block.drawBlock();
```

A callback is simply a function that is executed at a later time--usually after a long-running task has finally been completed.

Loading an image is a good example.  Consider this code:

```
function someCallbackFunction(){
    alert("The image has finally been fully loaded");
}

var image=new Image();

image.onload=someCallbackFunction;

image.src="yourImage.png";

alert("This code is last, but will execute before the onload function");
```

It will actually execute in this order:

1. The image object is created.

   var image=new Image();
2. The image object is told that when it's done fully loading the image it should execute the function called someCallbackFunction.

   image.onload=someCallbackFunction
3. The image is given a .src URL and begins the long process of downloading the image

   image.src="yourImage.png";
4. Any code after image.src="yourImage.png" will execute.
5. ...Sometime later...After the image is fully loaded, the image object will execute someCallbackFunction() and the alert will sound.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried it out and there is only one small issue. Since this is for a 2d game, I'm calling drawBlock() about 30 times a second, which results in the block flickering. Is this because it's loading the image anew for each frame, and do you know what would be the best way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, you image is being reloaded 30 times per second.  Take a look at this recoding that starts loading the image when Block is created and then draws it when block.drawBlock is called:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/cAR93/