# Get pixel RGB in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rgba, getimagedata

I have a function to get pixel data from a 14x14px png. I tested to see if img.src was valid, which it is. Any pixel coordinate I use returns an array filled with 0's.

```
var RGB = getPixel('spectrum2D.png', 5, 5)

console.log(RGB) // Uint8ClampedArray(4) [0, 0, 0, 0]

function getPixel(url, x, y) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 14
    canvas.height = 14
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
}
```

Comment: wait until the image is loaded

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654114/javascript-using-callback-to-draw-an-image-to-canvas?lq=1